# DOS to UNIX conversion

Tags: csv, powershell, line-endings

I have this code to remove return carriage (`^M`) characters to be absorbed by Unix. The below codes works, but I can't figure out how to:

1. loop through a number of CSVs (5), effectively using the for loop
2. replace the existing files with the new files

   ```
   $csv = (Get-Content -Raw *.csv) -replace "`r`n","`n"
   [io.file]::WriteAllText('C:\Powershell\test.csv', $csv)
   ```

Comment: Is this in unix? There is often a `dos2unix` program in bash

Comment: This is in Windows.  I am aware of the dos2unix but I am in the process of transitioning from batch to powershell.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Steve Not really. He has the conversion already worked out. The question is about how to apply it to a number of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted will take all CSV files and concatenate them to a single output file. You need enumerate and process the files individually. There's also no need to collect the content in a variable. Just pipe the modified content into `Set-Content`.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\some\folder' -Filter *.csv | ForEach-Object {
  (Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName) -replace "`r`n", "`n" | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```